# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" only in requests with Basic Authorization

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat, post, cors

I have an Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 server and jQuery ajax for request it. When I tried to send some request from a browser (which is at one domain) to server (that's at other) I found out about CORS and solved the problem by this way:
Add to the web.xml:

```html
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,
    X-Requested-With,accept,
    Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,
    Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization, Authorization, accept, Accept</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And this ajax starts to work:

```js
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://185.18.52.203:8080/registration',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"num": "123"}),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {$("p").text(textStatus);},
    success: function(data){$("p").text(data);}
  });
```

But when I try to do the same with Base Auth

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '//185.18.52.203:8080/create',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    //headers: {
      //"Authorization ": "Basic MTp5ZW5vdA==",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ": "*",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ": "POST",
      //"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ": "Authorization",
      //"Authorization": 'Basic MTp5ZW5vdA==',
    //},
    //crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({...}),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            //xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic MMt7DZ5vdA==");
            //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:", "POST");
            //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ", "*");
            },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {$("p").text(textStatus);},
    success: function(data){$("p").text(data);}
});
```

I have the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://185.18.52.203:8080/... Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.105' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I save my comments just because understanding that I tried a lot of things
Thanks